# how i can use multiple consumer in python-kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I see the docs.
https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html

I try Multiple Consumer.
but it is not working?
and how it is working?

What's wrong?

```
consumer1 = KafkaConsumer(
     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
     #auto_offset_reset='earliest' , # 'earliest',
     #enable_auto_commit= False ,
     group_id='sr',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
consumer1.subscribe("numtest")
consumer2 = KafkaConsumer(
     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
     #auto_offset_reset='earliest' , # 'earliest',
     #enable_auto_commit= False ,
     group_id='sr',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
consumer2.subscribe("numtest")
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         key_serializer = None ,                         
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
def on_send_success(record_metadata):
    print("topic : {} , partition : {} , offset : {}".\
          format( record_metadata.topic , record_metadata.partition , record_metadata.offset))

for msg , message in zip(consumer1 , consumer2) :
    print("="*50)
    print ("topic=%s partition=%d offset=%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                          message.offset, message.key,
                                          message.value))
    print ("topic=%s partition=%d offset=%d: key=%s value=%s" % (msg.topic, msg.partition,
                                          msg.offset, msg.key,
                                          msg.value))
    key = str(message.offset) + " " + str(msg.offset)
    producer.send('output', value= {  key : key }  ).add_callback(on_send_success)
    print("="*50)
```

In fact, what I want to do is I want two computers to do an ex input for model's presentation and merge two results.

Instead, I have to keep the same offset when I do merge.

After that, I want to send the result output topic.

my expected result is like this in `output` **topic** :

{ offset =  1 :  offest = 1} , { offset =  2 :  offest = 2 } , ....

please help me! I can't solve it

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify a bit more on what is your expected outcome?

If you are trying to,

1. Create two different consumers in which both consumer1 and consumer2 gets the same messages

   - For this, group id of both consumers should be different, try 'sr1' and 'sr2' as group ids. Try the following code

> ```
> consumer1 = KafkaConsumer(
>      bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
>      #auto_offset_reset='earliest' , # 'earliest',
>      #enable_auto_commit= False ,
>      group_id='sr',
>      value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
> consumer1.subscribe("numtest")
> consumer2 = KafkaConsumer(
>      bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
>      #auto_offset_reset='earliest' , # 'earliest',
>      #enable_auto_commit= False ,
>      group_id='sr',
>      value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
> consumer2.subscribe("numtest")
> ```

2. Create a consumer-group in which consumer1 gets some of the messages and consumer2 gets the rest of the message

   - If you are trying to achieve this, I think your current code will work as well, just keep in mind that you probably don't wanna do this as different consumers are usually spread across different processes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply!
In fact, what I want to do is I want two computers to do an ex input for model's presentation and merge two results. Instead, I have to keep the same offset when I do merge.  After that, I want to send the result output topic.  my expected result is like this in output topic : { offset =  1 :  offest = 1} , { offset =  2 :  offest = 2 } , ....
please help me! I can't solve it

Comment: Are they from two different topics? In that case, are you trying to do something like a Join (https://dzone.com/articles/join-semantics-in-kafka-streams)?

Comment: I want to combine the processed values between topic and each consumer with the same offset while using the same theme "numest" 
In addition, I want to use multiprocessing for each consumer.
for example {"same offset" , "consumer1_reuslt" + "consumer_result2"}
 {"0" , "C1 , 0.78 , C2 , 0.1"}
 {"1" , "C1 , 0.85 , C2 , 0.57"}